# Get public Facebook profile information (name, profile picture, etc.) with Facebook v2.5 SDK

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get public Facebook profile information from an user's ID. According to their site, this is what it should take:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'GET',
      '/{user-id}'
    );

    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
?>
```

However, when I replace `{user-id}` with my own ID, I get this error:

> Class 'FacebookRequest' not found

When I use their Graph API Explorer, it works perfectly and I can easily extract my information. However, when I press "Get Code" and paste it in, it looks exactly like my code above, but it just won't work. If I add in:

```
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
```

I now get this error:

> Undefined variable: session

I am really unsure what to do. I have tried following EVERY example for the past hour, but nothing seems to work.